# Apache 2.4 with PHP not working

Tags: apache-2.4

I'm trying to run Apache 2.4 on a windows 10 computer, but when I try add PHP to the server, it doesn't work.

This is what I have in the httpd.conf

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html
LoadModule php7_module "c:/php7/php7apache2_4.dll"
PHPIniDir "c:/php7"
```

I know it is something with PHP, because when I omit the stuff above, everything works correctly.